# iPad HTML Focus

Tags: jquery, html, ipad

I have an issue with focusing a text field on the iPad. Where I use:

```
$(document).bind("click",function(event) {
    alert('click');
    focusTextArea();
});
```

The focus is set to the text area, and a keyboard appears. However when called with touchend, `focusTextArea` is not called and the keyboard is not made visible. My `focusTextArea` function is:

```
function focusTextArea() {
    $('#textArea').focus();
}
```

Does anybody know why this occurs, and how I might be able to get this to work?

TIA,

Adam

Comment: Are you using the jquery plugin touchend?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you meant by "when called with touchend"?

Comment: @guanome- not using any plugins, just standard jquery.

Comment: @tim, Sorry I meant replacing the click event argument of bind with the touchend event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714084/autofocus-with-keyboard-in-an-ipad-html5-site and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287342/jquery-focus-method-on-the-ipad

Comment: I got around this by adding a div that covered the whole display area with some basic instruction in the middle "Tap to Begin".  Then bound a "tap" event to the div.  The tap then hid the div and set focus to the textbox.  That was the only way I could find to get around this crazy problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, focusing is not possible with the iPad. The only way the focus will be placed in the desired field is when the user 'clicks' on the desired field.

**Update 2015-01-08:**

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332160/540812) by [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821334/matt):

> ...
>   iOS will only allow focus to be triggered on other elements, from
>   within a function, if the first function in the call stack was
>   triggered by a non-programmatic event. In your case, the call to
>   setTimeout starts a new call stack, and the security mechanism kicks
>   in to prevent you from setting focus on the input.

Comment: Additionally, in an onclick event for any element, you can call focus() to another input.

Comment: not completely true: if the focus is triggered within the callback of a click event on another INPUT field, this actually works (unless you have an animation in between which seems to interrupt this option again...). so yes it does kinda (not) work, sort of :P

Comment: Any references to support that Bob? I know myself first hand that focus doesn't work properly. I'm just wondering if Apple has said anything about it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, I guess I have to bring you a bad news :-)

So much questions for "HOW DO I FOCUS ON AN INPUT FIELD ON IPAD USING CLICK HANDLER ?"
And sooooo much answers which doesn't really help ...

The bad news, which is not really a news, is that it isn't possible, because the focussed element will loose the focus again, while the operation of the clicked paragraph is subject to be finished.

The example above again here for explaination

```
$(document).bind("click",function(event) {
    alert('click');
    focusTextArea();
});
```

means:
1. focus on document
2. fire the click event (focus on textarea)
3. get back to document (document gets focus again)
4. finishig click event, document looses focus.

Now to the goooood news !

The final solution (tested an iPhone, iPad and android with native internet app, firefox and chrome) is:
Use touchend or mouseup instead !

```
$(document).bind("touchend",function(event) {
    alert('click');
    focusTextArea();
});
```

or

```
$(document).bind("mouseup",function(event) {
    alert('click');
    focusTextArea();
});
```

In combination with jquery plugin

```
* jQuery Browser Plugin v0.0.6
* https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin
```

I am using a small script which will detect platform (mobile or not) and set the correct clickhandler for later use.

```
var clickevent = '';
if ($.browser.mobile) clickevent = 'touchend';
else clickevent = 'click';
```

Now I can use the following

```
$(document).bind(clickevent,function(event) {
    alert('click');
    focusTextArea();
});
```

which will work for both, desktops and mobil devices.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, 'touchend' doesn't work in every case, but 'mouseup' does ! Please tryout and find your best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [fastclick js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick), should work.
Check [this](http://ftlabs.github.io/fastclick/examples/focus.html) example (also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287478/mobile-safari-autofocus-text-field/7332160#7332160)).

Also I've made this [`jsfiddle` example](https://jsfiddle.net/ranbuch/vksh3b6c/1/) which seems to work on iPad (Chrome and Safari).

Hope this helps.