# Javascript for focussing the text field in Ipad

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPad HTML Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978470/ipad-html-focus)

How do focus a textfield on an iPad from JavaScript?

`object.focus()` is not working.

Comment: In my experience this doesn't work. Seems to be a bug in mobile webkit. Hopefully more qualified folks will answer.