# JQuery switching input text fields on the ipad

Tags: jquery, ios, input, focus, keyup

I have a shopping cart app that needs to take credit cards.  The credit card numbers get entered into 4 different input fields side by side, because that's how most credit cards are formatted, 16-digits, divided into groups of 4.  I have a neat effect to help make filling out these form fields easier. When the user types in 4 characters, I automatically set the focus to the next input field.

This doesn't work on the iOS devices.  When I change the focus, the keyboard drops and nothing else happens.

To facilitate this i am capturing keypresses:

```
$('input:regex(id, ^cc)').unbind("keyup").keyup(function(e) {
var element = e.target;
if($(element).val().length == 4) {
            var cid = $(element).prop('id');

            var prefix  = cid.substr(0, 4);
            var number  = cid.substr(4, 1);
            var postfix = cid.substr(5, cid.length);

            //Use closest UL so that we stay within the bounds of this card
            $(element).closest('ul').find('#' + prefix + ++number + postfix + ':first').focus();
        }
});
```

The entry fields have enumerated ids 'cc-1', 'cc-2' etc which explains the last line in the jquery callback.  Please ignore any syntax issues.  I've scrubbed this code and might have made some mistakes along the way.  Quite frankly i don't think there's anything wrong with my code, i just think it's an iOS thing.

I know that you can't make the keyboard appear without user interaction, but isn't a key press a user interaction?  Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPad HTML Focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978470/ipad-html-focus)

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate, because i am doing this via user interaction.  I guess the question I have is does key press count as a user interaction?