# How to make twitter boot-strap modal box focus work properly in iPad?

Tags: jquery, ipad, twitter-bootstrap

In a php Web application, I am using twitter boot-strap modal box. When I click on the save button in the form, modal box is shown and the default focus is working correctly.
But in iPad, when I tap the go button focus is not working.

Here is the twitter bootstrap modal code I am using:

```
<div class="modal hide" id="confirm-password">                    
   <div class="modal-header">    
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">    
       <input type="text" placeholder="Your Current Password" value="" name="currentpassword" id="currentpassword" autofocus>                      
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">                           
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS Code :

```
$('#confirm-password').on('shown', function () {
   jQuery('input:text:visible:first', this).focus(); //focus for input
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a bootstrap thing and not a general input thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `focus` does not work on iPads. The user has to tap the input in question. This is not Bootstrap-specific.

See:
[iPad HTML Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978470/ipad-html-focus)

What you may be able to do is [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) a `click` or `touchstart` event on the input in question when the dialog is shown for touchscreen devices.

Answer (score 0):

if you add your web application to *home screen*, this will work on recent iOS.