# document.getElementById().focus() not working on a mobile

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, mobile, focus

I am using this line of code:

```
  document.getElementById("myfield").focus()
```

in JavaScript, to bring the focus to a given text input field.

On a computer (I am using a Mac) it works fine, but on a mobile (iPhone, iPad) it does not work.

I did the experiment both with `Firefox` and `Safari`, the result is the same.

Does anyone know why and how to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mobile Safari: Javascript focus() method on inputfield only works with click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204571/mobile-safari-javascript-focus-method-on-inputfield-only-works-with-click)

Comment: Use .click() instead... Here is the nice reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204571/mobile-safari-javascript-focus-method-on-inputfield-only-works-with-click

Comment: It seems that ios focus doesn't work => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978470/ipad-html-focus

Comment: @UllasHunka You should really learn [how to handle duplicate questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)