# Set focus and start typing with JQUery on IPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, input, focus

I have a problem with focus on IPad.

How to set focus on input field and start typing text by showing the keyboard? With JQuery

Here [JQuery focus() method on the ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287342/jquery-focus-method-on-the-ipad) 
is said, that Apple "doesn't want the keyboard to appear except on user demand". Is it really so? Or exists some way to manage this problem?

Comment: Doesn't the keyboard appear by default when clicked on a input field?

Comment: yes, it appears.. but unfortunately my input field is initially hidden